# Excel: Lookup Multiple values with duplicates in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to link multiple lists and show all the values. Including duplicates.

My worksheet has data in 11 Columns. One column with Products(which can appear multiple times) and the rest with Store(which sell the products, no store sells the same product). 
A small example here:

[image: Example]

I've made a helper column(A) using the following formula : `=B2&COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)` . The helper column counts how many time a product show up in the  Products Column(B). I thought it was needed.

I've managed to sort the data a bit using `=VLOOKUP($C$2&ROWS($L$1:L1),$A$2:$C$11,2,0)` like this :

**Result**

[image: Result Attempt]

But I want to sort the data in a single Column for each store like this:

**Desired Result**

[image: Desired Result]

, without having to change the formula every 2-3 rows, as some store have 30 or so products.
 Is this something achievable with either formulas or VBA?

I would like to have the results in one column :

- List Store 1 items as many times as they appear in Product column.
- If an item(from Store 1) doesn't show up in Product column show "Product name -"
- Product Column can have repeatable items
- Each store has different products, so there's no conflict there.
- If possible, since i have they Helper Column, if a product shows up 4 times, when i drag the formula in the 5th row it should jump to the next product.

Hope this is clear enough. Thank you

Later Edit: 
Maybe this helps a bit in understanding what I want to obtain.

Column 1 helper I've added it to count how many times a product shows up in Column 2. 
I want to get a separate column, which shows the items in Column 3(store1) x how many times they appear in Products Column. 
In the example above Store1 has product "Hansa" which appears 4 times in Product Column so it should appear 4 times in the separate column, after it there's product "Korek" which appears 1 time in Product Column so it should appear one time in the separate column under "Hansa" and so on. So basically I want to compare the third column to the second and show to values in the third x times they appear in the second in a different column.

Comment: It is not very clear, really. Column1 Helper, Column 2 Product, Column 3 (Store?). So how it is linked the Store and the product? Which store have which product? There is no issue in what are you looking for, but the information seems not to be very clear. At least the relations

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego I've added some more info into the question, maybe in clears up. In short, I want to compare the values in Column 3 against Column 2 and in let's say Column 4 I want to obtain the values in Column 3 x times they appear in Column 2. Column 1 just counts how many times a value appears in Column 2.

Comment: Now it is clear. With your actual sheet (Your sample), in column D place: IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$B$2:$B$11),0,0),0)),"Product Name -") and on column E place COUNTIF($D$2:$D$11,"="&D2,$A$2:$A$11) both in row 2. Now you can drag it. In column D you will get the products that appears on Column B (not repeated), if not, it will place "Product Name -" and in column E you will get how many times it appears. Later copy and paste as per your needs. Hope it helps.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego Seems to be working, is there a way to get the results in one column. For example in Column D: Hansa will appear 4 times, then switch to the next product. Take a look at my desired results image to get an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula uses `F1` as a *helper cell*, which is needed to count the matches in the product list.

Enter this `FormulaArray` in `F1`:

```
=SUM( IF( ISERROR( MATCH( $B$2:$B$11, $C$2:$C$6, 0 ) ), 0, 1 ) )
```

[image]

Enter this formula in `E2:E11`:

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( $C$2:$C$6,
AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
MATCH( $B$2:$B$11, $C$2:$C$6, 0 ),
ROWS( E$2:E2 ) ) ),
IFERROR( INDEX( $C$2:$C$6,
AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
ROW(E:E) / ISERROR( MATCH( $C$2:$C$6, $B$2:$B$11, 0 ) ),
ROWS( E$2:E2 ) - $F$1 ) ) & "-", "" ) )
```

[image]

*Note that the helper column `A` is not needed.*